# Is this error Unix/Linux specific in internet browsers OR Linux VPN related?

Tags: debian, openvpn, firefox, browser, troubleshooting

I want to know if the following problem is only in Unix/Linux systems and their internet browsers, since it occurs only with my Linux/Chromebook machines with VPN, but not in Windows machines with VPN. 
It occurs at [areena.yle.fi](https://areena.yle.fi/tv) which is Finnish Government media company for TV. It requires IP in Finland so I use NordVPN with Finnish servers. I get the error only in Linux systems and Chromebook, but not in Android and Windows systems. 
The error started about 2 weeks ago. 
It was first temporal, but now, all the time on Linux/Unix systems. 
I already contacted the tech support of the source but they have not confirmed the problem. 
Error:

> No KS where KS is required
>
> We're sorry, access to this content is restricted.

Picture

[image]

### Trying other user agent (imbuedHope)

I install the [app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher/ffhkkpnppgnfaobgihpdblnhmmbodake/). I try many user agents: Safari, Android, IE versions, ..., but still, I get the error

### NordVPN support reply on the matter

They write about the case here:

```
Unfortunately it seems like we are currently experiencing issues regarding this streaming site accessibility.

We have forwarded this information to our system administrators. They will look for a fix regarding this issue.

I am sorry for the inconvenience.
```

At 14th March, the problem still persists.

OS: Linux Debian Stretch 9.x
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA R4028T
Internet Browsers: Chrome latest, Firefox latest
VPN: NordVPN Finland IP addresses

Comment: Have you tried switching user agents? It looks like someone might have turned on a content restriction for unix at first glance.

Comment: @imbuedHope Testing, but still, I get find a soluion by changirg the user agent. The error remains.

Comment: Comes up fine for me on Mint 18.x using latest Chrome (not chromium)

Comment: @ivanivan Can you explain why it works in Mint but not in Debian?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 - nope.  Could be an IP based block, etc.   But I can say that the site doesn't care that I'm running Chrome in Linux.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an issue related to the VPN provider rather than the underlying OS

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the site is using [Kaltura Video Platform](http://player.kaltura.com/docs/index.php?path=CustomMessageAccessControlKS) and the "KS" in the error message refers to a Kaltura Session.

[This document](https://knowledge.kaltura.com/kalturas-api-authentication-and-security) describes the things the Kaltura platform can use for access control and session limits. It might be helpful in identifying the important difference between the working and failing browsers.